# How to access model properties to create texboxfor in IEnumerable Type?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to create  strongly typed textbox using Html helper in `@model List<Proj.xx.MyClass>`. But I am not able to access the properties of `MyClass`.

can anyone please help me sort out the issues?

```
  public class MyClass
{

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string AddNote { get; set; }
}
```

View

```
 @model List<Proj.xx.MyClass>
         @foreach (var item in Model)
         {
          <tr>
            <td>
                <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#AddNote">

                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
              </a>

            </td>                                                                

        </tr>
        }


 <div class="modal fade" id="AddNote" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">                                       
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.AddNote)                             

                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" id="reset" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>              
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Not clear what you are wanting to do. Are you wanting to edit the `AddNote` for each item in the collection?

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I have updated my question. I want to add modal popup upon click on Name. And in that modal, I want to add textbox.

Comment: Since you want to edit a Note for a single `MyClass`, then you should generate the  modals html using `@Html.Action()` to call a server method that returns a partial view (whose model is a new instance of `MyClass`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Can you please show me some sample code so that I can follow. I am not able to get what you said.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Yes please. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a `ChildActionOnly` method that returns a partial view of you modal based on an instance of `MyClass`

```
[ChildOnlyAction]
public PartialViewResult _Note()
{
    MyClass model = new MyClass();
    .... // set any defaults if required
    return PartialView("_Note", model));
}
```

`_Note.cshtml` partial

```
@model MyClass
<div class="modal fade" id="AddNote" role="dialog">
    ....
    <div class="modal-body">
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Name)                             
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AddNote)                             
    </div>
    ....
</div>
```

And then in the main view, include it using

```
@Html.Action("_Note") // assumes its in the same controller
```

or

```
@{ Html.RenderAction("_Note"); }
```

Note that I included a hidden input for the `Name` property assuming you will also want to post back that value as well so that you know which `MyClass` the Note is associated with (although you really should also have a ID property for that as well). In addition, your html should also include a `<form>` element to submit the edited value.

Then you will also need some JavaScript to assign the current value to the inputs assuming you are editing existing records.

Comment: Great help Stephen.

Comment: I need one more help which is related to the code which you have shown here. As you have seen the modal pop up where I want to submit the input. Can you please show me the way the grab particular row Id when submitting the modal pop up.

Comment: I assume you want to set the value of the hidden input? If so, you could give the link a class name, say `<a class="showdialog" ...... >`, then use `$('.showdialog').click(function() { $('#Name').val($(this).text()); })`

Comment: One small doubt, I have `@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)` as well in my main view and I want to pass this Id when I submit the modal popup. And I tried `$('#Id').val($(this).text());` but not getting the Id value of that particular row. Please help me to write JQuery function. I got lost here. Please help me.

Comment: There is nothing in your question about a `@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)` and without seeing the full code for your view its not possible to guess the correct jQuery selectors.

Comment: You should ask a new question with the relevant view code and script you have tried (Its late here and I will be signing off shortly)

Comment: Sure Stephen. I will post a new question. If you get a time then please have a look tomorrow.

Comment: Can you please have a look on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51478630/how-to-retrieve-value-from-table-row-and-use-that-value-in-modal-pop-up-submit-c)

Comment: Sorry to interrupt you, Stephen. Can you please have a look on my another question. Thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176598/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-mvc).