# How to retrieve value from table row and use that value in modal pop up submit click in MVC application?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have Index view where I am displaying list of data in a table. On each row second column `Name` click, I have displayed a modal up where I have created `TextAreaFor` to insert some input and then on `submit` button click, the data should store in respective row in database table. I got stuck how to insert modal input value in respective row in database table.

Please help me. Your help is highly appreciated.

```
 public class MyClass
    {
      public int Id {get;set;}
      public string Name { get; set; }
      public string AddNote { get; set; }
    }
```

Home Controller

```
[ChildActionOnly]
        public PartialViewResult _pNote()
        {
         MyClass model = new MyClass();
         return PartialView("_pNote", model);
        }

      [ChildActionOnly]
        [HttpPost]
        public PartialViewResult _pNote(int Id)
        {
            MyClass model = new MyClass();
             model=submitrecord(Id);
            return PartialView("_pNote", model);
        }
```

Index View

```
               @model List<Proj.xx.MyClass>
                       <table>
                        <tr >
                            <th>
                                @Html.DisplayName("Id")
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                @Html.DisplayName("Name")
                            </th>                           

                        </tr>
                        @foreach (var item in Model)
                       {
                        <tr>
                               <td>
                                  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)                                
                                </td>                           

                                <td>
                           <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#AddNote">                                      
                                  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                                </a>

                   </td>     

                        </tr>
                   }

                    </table>
@{ Html.RenderAction("_pNote"); }
```

_pNote Partial

```
@model Proj.xx.MyClass

@using (Html.BeginForm("_pNote", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @Id = "form" }))
{
    <div class="modal fade" id="AddNote" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">  

                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
                    @Html.TextAreaFor(m=>m.AddNote)
                </div>

                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" id="reset" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

                    <button type="button" data-assigned="@Model.Id" id="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

JQuery

```
$('#Submit').click(function () {
             debugger;
           var id=  $('#Id').val($(this).text());                
             var path = '@Url.Action("_pNote", "Home")?id=' + id;
             path= encodeURI(path);
         });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use Ajax call. and give all the links a class 'link' for example and add a data attribute for each link to store the Id :

```
<td>
    <a class="link" data-id="@Model.Id">                                      
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
    </a>
</td>
```

and then you get the id and send an ajax call to your action and put the result (html) in a container :

```
$('.link').click(function(){
   var id = $(this).data('id');

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.GetActionUrl("_pNote", "Home")',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {Id: id},
            success: function (res) {
                $("#modalContainer").html(res)
            }
        });
});
```

and in the view :

```
@model List<Proj.xx.MyClass>
                       <table>
                        <tr >
                            <th>
                                @Html.DisplayName("Id")
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                @Html.DisplayName("Name")
                            </th>                           

                        </tr>
                        @foreach (var item in Model)
                       {
                        <tr>
                               <td>
                                  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)                                
                                </td>                           

                                <td>
                           <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#AddNote">                                      
                                  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                                </a>

                   </td>     

                        </tr>
                   }

                    </table>
<div id="modalContainer"></div>
```

Comment: This is not working as expected. `var id = $(this).data('id');` gives me Id of that particular row but my concern is that how to use the value when I submit modal pop up. As you can see that this is [ChildActionOnly]` attribute. Please suggest me.

Comment: It is also throwing error `The action '_pNote' is accessible only by a child request.`